# Method class crashes on sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

So I have an Activity and call another class and as soon as it tries to get the shared preferences it crashes.

Here is the code of my call in the Activity

```
Methods_play test1 = new Methods_play(); 
String[] tmp1 = test1.pewpew(level);
```

and here the code from my method class

```
package


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

    public class Methods_play extends Activity {

        public String[] pewpew(int level) {

            //GETS STUFF
            Random rn = new Random(); 
            !!!HERE IS THE ERROR!!!    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            //SOME CODE

            //RETRUNS ARRAY
            String ar[] = new String[2];
            ar[0]= button1text;
            ar[1]= button2text;
            return ar;

        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have declared it in the manifest file (and i didnt but it crashed anyway). On normal Activitys the get shared preferences code works.

Its the first time i tried to use a method class in android so im pretty sure i fucked it up.

On a side note: Are there any good tutorials on this?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT (line 23 is where i say it crashes, 159 is the call to the method and 143 is the call to the defineqacall method in the oncreate method of the activity):

```
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001): Process: eu.jbr.quizexo, PID: 14001
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.jbr.quizexo/eu.jbr.quizexo.Career_Play}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:173)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at eu.jbr.quizexo.Methods_play.defineqa(Methods_play.java:23)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at eu.jbr.quizexo.Career_Play.defineqacall(Career_Play.java:159)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at eu.jbr.quizexo.Career_Play.onCreate(Career_Play.java:143)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
09-03 01:36:01.742: E/AndroidRuntime(14001):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Crashes. How? Stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Methods_play extends Activity` you **must** implement certain methods such as `onCreate(Bundle myBundle)`. Also, `SharedPreferences` needs a `Context` so you can't initialize it **before** `onCreate()` since there is no `Context` available. Try something like

```
// declare it
SharedPreferences prefs;

public class Methods_play extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle someBundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(someBundle);
        //initialize it
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

As MikeM pointed out in comments, it doesn't appear that you need to extend `Activity`. Don't extend anything, create a constructor, pass it your `Activity Context`, and use that to access `SharedPreferences`.

```
public class Methods_play {

    // create a member variable for your context
    Context mContext;

    //Create the constructor which takes a context
    public void Methods_play(Context c)
    {
         mContext = c;
    }

    public String[] pewpew(int level) {

        //GETS STUFF
        Random rn = new Random(); 

        // Use your context below
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(getResources()
               .getString(R.string.preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

Comment: Given the first code block in the post, I'm thinking that `Methods_play` doesn't need to be an Activity subclass, and the OP just made it as such so that `getSharedPreferences()` would resolve. I think a constructor with a Context parameter is probably what is needed here.

Comment: @MikeM. that's very likely. I just can't consider every possible situation. The point is, that `SharedPreferences` needs a `Context`

Comment: Understood. That comment was more for the OP anyway. I know you know what you're doing. ;-)

Comment: I think Mike M. is correct but I have no idea what hes talking about. I did what codeMagic said and now it crashes somewhere else and it says something about context wrapper. (it crashes on Integer tmp3= getResources().getInteger(getResources().getIdentifier("player"+level, "integer", getPackageName()));    )

Comment: @user3254126 that call needs to be called with a correct `Context`

Comment: any tip or idea how i can achieve this?